# Tap gesture fires on single tap before conforming to double tap requirement

Tags: swift

I've looked at previous answers to this question, but the solutions don't seem to work in my case (e.g. adding a requirement for the gesture recognizer to fail).

I have hooked up my view to a tap gesture recognizer, and I'm trying to use the following handler in my code:

```
@IBAction func doubleTapView(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

    if gesture.state == .Ended {
        print("Works")
    }
}
```

This is what happens:

The first tap will print "Works".
From then on, it will require the double-tap to print "Works"

How do I eliminate it printing on the first tap before it defaults to the correct and intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the number of touches before the `@IBAction` function call.

There are two ways here:

Either in storyboard

[image: Set it here]

Or create an IBOutlet and set it in the `viewDidLoad()` function.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this is the case?

Comment: The "numberOfTapsRequired" property of the tap gesture recognizer is part of its setup, therefore you must do it first, so the IBAction will get fired after a double tap (and not after a single tap - its default value)